# Retrieve JSON data From JQuery ajax(), PHP and MySQL using custom MVC

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I have been searching everywhere and I am not getting anywhere. This is what I am using:
Custom PHP MVC
this is what I am trying to get:
From userView.php I want to replace an id="ShowName" with JSON data from a ajax Call using JQuery

This is what I have:
**userController.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $this->getView('users', $this->object->getUser($_POST['id']));
}
```

**userModel.php**

```
public function getUser($id) {
    $this->user = array();

    parent::getConnection();
    $this->sql = $this->dbh->query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE idUser='". $id ."'");
    parent::errorHandler();
    $this->results = $this->sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $this->user[] = array(
        'name' => $this->results['name'],
        'lastname' => $this->results['lastname'],
        'email' =>  $this->results['email']
        );
    $obj['user'] = $this->user;

    parent::closeConnection();
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    print json_encode($obj);

}
```

**userView.php**

```
<select class="form-control blue select" id="getUserID">
    <option value="default">Seleccione un Usuario</option>
    <?php $this->object->getUserslist();?>
</select>

<span id="name"></span>
```

**Method getUsersList() inside userModel**

```
public function getUsersList() {

    parent::getConnection();
    $this->sql = $this->dbh->query("SELECT * FROM User ORDER BY name ASC");
    parent::errorHandler();
    while($this->results = $this->sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $this->results['idUser'] . "'>" . $this->results['name'] . "</option>";
    }
    parent::closeConnection();

}
```

**JQuery**

```
$("#getUserID").change(function(){
    var userID = $("#getUserID").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'user',
        data: 'id='+userID,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            alert(obj.name)
        }
    });
});
```

It retrieves JSON data at the very top of the html file, but the alert is not prompting, so I guess it gets data before the success is called.

Direct Question: How can I retrieve the JSON data from PHP so I can use it in html from JQUERY ajax Response?

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In userModel.php

change

```
$this->user[] = array(
    'name' => $this->results['name'],
    'lastname' => $this->results['lastname'],
    'email' =>  $this->results['email']
    );
$obj['user'] = $this->user;
```

to:

```
$obj = array(
    'name' => $this->results['name'],
    'lastname' => $this->results['lastname'],
    'email' =>  $this->results['email']
    );
```

See if the alert prompt returns what you expect.

Comment: Nope, nothing, the alert does not even work at all, but I do get the JSON data, but like I said, in console and above the html code

Comment: @Jorge try console.log(data); and comment out the alert and see what shows up in the your console. Also try doing console.log(obj);

Comment: Also, in your developer toolbar, check the network tab and see what the response is on the ajax call.

Comment: Same thing. Liek I said, in console I can see the data, but I cannot access it from JQuery, neither from alert or into the id I mentioned.
in net (btw, using Firebug) I just can see the html code as response, no post, post only shows up in console :(

Comment: copy and paste what the console.log returns in the console tab.

Comment: {"user":[{"name":"UserFirst ","lastname":"UserLast","email":"email@email.com","phone":"0","mobile":"NULL","birthday":"NULL","id":"2467","avatar":null}]}<!Doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">....
As you can see the JSON comes up well, but the ajax is not getting it, I think it has to be something about DOM

Comment: I added statusCode into the ajax call after success and it works, it gives me the 200 Status Code as good, I also adde before success a beforeSend just to see if it was doing something, and everything works as expected, but nothing inside success, nothing that I do inside success works, maybe that can help us

Comment: Change your post data to - data: {id: userID},

Comment: Same. But I added this line to the statusCode instead of the success: 
$("#name").text("200"+data);. I get 200[object object]

Comment: Now I added: var user = $.parseJSON(data); $("#name").text("200"+user); and it gave me SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data in Firebug console

Comment: do console.log(data); within success and you should be able to figure out how that data object is constructed and you'll be on your way.